# GenericObjectPool monitoring and administration via JMX

Tags: java, jmx, apache-commons

I have some custom java objects in pool, using Apache Commons GenericObjectPool. Its important to see in real-time pool properties, like active objects in pool, and to send notifications for administrator when pool size reach critical value.

I decided to use JMX, and I just wonder, may be already exists some MBean implementations for GenericObjectPool, from Apache or third-party developers.

Comment: Also check jmx2graphite (https://github.com/logzio/jmx2graphite) to dump JMX into Graphite in one command line without installation nor hefty configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://jmxtrans.googlecode.com/ as your JMX query engine. You can use that tool to either send the data to Graphite or write your own output format to send the data to wherever you want.